# In call volume root modify

Tags: root-access, htc-one, volume

I have a HTC One m7 international. It has root access. Android lollipop 5.0.2

The in call volume is too low despite being on max volume.

Which file in the root system should I modify to increase the max volume? What line of code corresponds to this setting?

Thanks vm

Comment: android version?

Comment: It is lollipop 5.0.2

Comment: Turn on adb in phone,connect the phone to system and run this command in system connected `adb shell service call audio 7 i32 3 i32 0 i32 1` Source: [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391326/how-to-change-the-volume-using-adb-shell-service-call-audio)

Comment: Thankyou it seems to have increased the volume...  Can you explain a bit what that line of code means and how it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach achieves desired functionality by communicating with Android APIs at [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) level making use of [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html)

---

Run the command:

```
adb shell service call audio 7 i32 3 i32 0 i32 1
```

Here, the service `call` refers to `IAudioService`. Click [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/73e23e2/media/java/android/media/IAudioService.aidl)  for more info.

- `7` is the function named `setStreamVolume`. It is the 7th in the list of functions in the interface `IAudioService`. Verify it [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/73e23e2/media/java/android/media/IAudioService.aidl). (`setStreamVolume` takes 3 parameters `streamType`, `index`, `flag`)
- `i32` is to write the integer INT into the send parcel. (Alternatively we can make use of `s16` for UTF-16 string)
- `3` is `streamType`value. (Value `1` → phone, `3` → speaker, `4` → alarm, `6` → bluetooth)
- `0` is `index` value and `1` is `flag` value

See the source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27391326/how-to-change-the-volume-using-adb-shell-service-call-audio).

Comment: But how can op set that for every call? Or is using it once persistent?

Comment: @cde Changing once is enough,  no need to change it before every call

Comment: "7 i32 3 i32 0 i32 1" - I don't get it, why is the index=0 ? Isn't it the volume value? And what is the meaning of flag=1 ? Can you, please, clear up this issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**For Android 10**

```
adb shell media volume --show --stream 1 --set 1
```

**example :**

```
/ $ media volume --show --stream 4 --set 1
[v] will control stream=4 (STREAM_ALARM)
[v] will set volume to index=1
[v] Connecting to AudioService
```

Specific usage

```
usage: media [subcommand] [options]
       media dispatch KEY
       media list-sessions
       media monitor <tag>
       media volume [options]

media dispatch: dispatch a media key to the system.
                KEY may be: play, pause, play-pause, mute, headsethook,
                stop, next, previous, rewind, record, fast-forword.
media list-sessions: print a list of the current sessions.
media monitor: monitor updates to the specified session.
                       Use the tag from list-sessions.
media volume:  the options are as follows:
                --stream STREAM selects the stream to control, see AudioManager.STREAM_*
                                controls AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC if no stream is specified
                --set INDEX     sets the volume index value
                --adj DIRECTION adjusts the volume, use raise|same|lower for the direction
                --get           outputs the current volume
                --show          shows the UI during the volume change
        examples:
                adb shell media volume --show --stream 3 --set 11
                adb shell media volume --stream 0 --adj lower
                adb shell media volume --stream 3 --get
```