# HTC One M7 Volume fail

Tags: htc-one, microphone, volume

Like others, the microphone on my HTC One M7 is patchy. I can hear people fine, but they say I'm echoey, far away, quiet. It seems to have become worse too. I believe it might be to do with the noise cancelling mic [as mentioned here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2262648) although I don't know why it would be deteriorating if that's the case.

I don't have root access or I could [try this fix](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124249/in-call-volume-root-modify).

Apart from the root fix or the [old toothbrush fix](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/2ccet7/attention_htc_one_m7_m8_owners_brushing_your/), is there anything else I can try?

Keen to keep my nice old HTC. Currently running 5.0.2.