# Increase target device Volume to maximum using adb command - Android Pie version

Tags: audio, 9.0-pie, volume

How to increase target device Volume to maximum using adb command on android pie version. I have tried below commands in adb, but volume did not volume got increased.

`adb shell service call audio 7 i32 3 i32 0 i32 1`

Comment: See https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218574/96277

Comment: Since Android 8 there is `adb sheel media volume` available. To get a well-formatted values of [volume streams](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-8.0.0_r1/media/java/android/media/AudioManager.java#318): `for s in $(seq 0 100); do media volume --stream $s --get 2>/dev/null | awk -F'[()= ]' '{if($3=="control") printf "%-22s %-3s: ",$7,$5} {if($2=="volume") printf "%-3s %s \n",$4,$7}' | grep ^STREAM || break; done`. You will get all stream names/numbers, their current values and possible values.

Comment: To set media volume (MUSIC_STREAM) to maximum: `media volume --stream 3 --set 25`. Where `3` is media volume stream and `25` is its maximum value. It's also possible to use `service call` as explained in above linked answer. Are you trying to change in-call earpiece volume or some other?